# Создание сложных веб-приложений

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Ниже есть картинка сайта. Как такое создается? С помощью каких средств? Знаю, что такое можно сделать с помощью WebAssembly, но данный сайт сделан не с WebAssembly.

[Гифка imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbc9I.jpg)

Comment: Например, можно через [Three.js](https://threejs.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот простенький пример на three.js с похожим функционалом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype.setAttribute=THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype.addAttribute;
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, innerWidth/innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0,15,15);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

addEventListener('resize', () => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
let material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
add(new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 ), -2);
add(new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 32, 32), 2 );
scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(50, 10, 0x666666, 0x444444));

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function add(geometry, dx) {
  let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 ), material);
  mesh.position.x = dx;
  scene.add(mesh);
  let control = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  control.addEventListener('dragging-changed', e => controls.enabled = !e.value);
  scene.add(control);
  control.attach(mesh);
}

render();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; overflow:hidden}
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/107/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js"></script>
```